# Categorize a list of names from database

Tags: database, arrays, sorting, categories, alphabetical

I have a database that contains names. I'm needing to take those names and sort them alphabetically into 4 ARRAY's -> (A-F) (G-L) (M-R) (S-Z). Any strategies out there that i could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the database 4 times, once for each range. A query looks like this:

```
select * from T where Name >= 'G' and name < 'M' order by name
```